# need the userInput_1 to update

Tags: python

I'm making a program that organizes money and but the user input doesn't work update

I have tried to use the get(), and set() but I cannon't seem to get anything to work. Also when I run  the program the user input value display a number that I didn't even give it.

```
root = Tk()

lab = Label(root)
lab.pack()

def clock():
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("Time: %H:%M:%S")
    lab.config(text=time)
    #lab['text'] = time
    root.after(1000, clock) # run itself again after 1000 ms

def userInputSaved():
    global userInput_1
    global userInput_2
    global userInput_3
    userInput_1 = userInput_1.get()
    userInput_2 = userInput_2.get()
    userInput_3 = userInput_3.get()

clock()

a = 0
if a >= 0:
    moneyPaid = Label(root, text = 'Please enter the amount of money you 
have made this month')
    moneyPaid.pack()
    userInput_1 = Entry(root)
    userInput_1.pack()
    a = a + 1

if a == 1:
    bills = Label(root, text = 'Please enter the amount of money you need 
to pay bills with')
    bills.pack()
    userInput_2 = Entry(root)
    userInput_2.pack()
    a = a + 1

if a == 2:
    saved = Label(root, text = 'Please enter the amount of money you want 
the save this month')
    saved.pack()
    userInput_3 = Entry(root)
    userInput_3.pack()
    a = a + 1

if a == 3:
    afterBills = Label(root, text = 'This is the amount of money you have 
after paying the bills: $' + str(userInput_1))
    afterBills.pack()

    afterSaved = Label(root, text = 'This is the amount of money you after 
putting back savings: $')
     afterSaved.pack()

    spending = Label(root, text = 'So the amount of money that you are 
able to use anything with is $')
    spending.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The result is that when the user input's a number that it is stored and used later.

Comment: You say that you "cannot seem to get anything to work", but it's not clear what is actually happening and what you expect to happen. In your code, nothing ever calls `userInputSaved`, and it's body is somewhat nonsensical as it tries to reference a nonexistent `self` variable. Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Show us what you expect the example code to do, and what it is doing instead.

Comment: I posted more of the code fixing what I believe that you were referencing hope it is more readable